# Separate two loops in java

Tags: java, loops

I should write a program that reads balance and interest rate, and displays the value of the account in ten years with anually, monthly and daily compounds.

I have written for yearly compounding and for monthly. In the second loop for monthly rate, program reads value of "balance" after compounding yearly, while I need it read primary value.  How is it possible to separate two loops, so they do not influence each other? Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class BankInterest {
    public static void main(String []args) {
        System.out.println("Please enter your balance: ");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        double balance = keyboard.nextDouble();
        int years = 0;
        int months = 0;
        int days = 0;
        System.out.println("Please enter the ann1ual interest rate in decimal form: ");
        double interestRate = keyboard.nextDouble();

        while (years<10) {
            double interest = balance * interestRate;
            balance = balance + interest;
            years++;

        }
        System.out.println("Balance after 10 years with annual interest is " + balance);

        while (months<120) {
            double interest = balance * interestRate/12;
            balance = balance + interest;
            months++;
        }
        System.out.println("Balance after 10 years with monthly interest rate is " + balance);
    }

}
```

When program is run and I input 100 for balance and 0.02 to interest rate, yearly compounding works well and displays:
Balance after 10 years with annual interest is 121.89944199947573

And second loop takes this value as balance and displays:
Balance after 10 years with monthly interest rate is 148.86352955791543

While, if my code was right it should display this number: 122.119943386

Comment: Perhaps reset the balance in between?

Comment: `balance` in the 1st while loop influences `balance` in the 2nd while loop because they have the same name. I imagine you don't want that

Comment: you can either assign balance back to the initial value or use another variable

Comment: Excuse me, I am beginner in Java. How is it possible to reset it? Thank you

Comment: @user3531903 FYI there are closed-form expressions (annuities) for that. If you persist in using loops, be aware that you are computing explicitly the terms within the sum.

Comment: Please don't use a floating point double to represent real balances.

Comment: Thank you! Actually, as I said I am beginner and this exercise is after chapter about loops, in my book.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to use int but there is syntax error while using it in loop, because interest is double (for the reason that interestRate is double) @Bathsheba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place both loops in different functions and pass both balance and interesRate as arguments, like below.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BankInterest {
    static public double annualInterest(double balance, double interestRate) {
         int years = 0;
         while (years < 10) {
            double interest = balance * interestRate;
            balance = balance + interest;
            years++;
        }

        return balance;
    }

    static public double monthlyInterest(double balance, double interestRate) {
      int months = 0;
         while (months < 120) {
            double interest = balance * interestRate/12;
            balance = balance + interest;
            months++;
        }

        return balance;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter your balance: ");
        double balance = keyboard.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Please enter the ann1ual interest rate in decimal form: ");
        double interestRate = keyboard.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Balance after 10 years with annual interest is " + 
        annualInterest(balance, interestRate));
        System.out.println("Balance after 10 years with monthly interest rate is " + 
        monthlyInterest(balance, interestRate));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare two different variables for initial balance and updated balance so that you can access the original balance in both loops. I have shown this below.

```
public static void main(String []args) {
System.out.println("Please enter your balance: ");
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
double startingBalance = keyboard.nextDouble();
double finalBalance=0;
int years = 0;
int months = 0;
int days = 0;
System.out.println("Please enter the ann1ual interest rate in decimal form: ");
double interestRateYearly = keyboard.nextDouble();
double interstRateMonthly = interestRateYearly;
double interstRateDayliy = interestRateYearly;

while (years<10) {
    double interest = startingBalance * interestRateYearly ;
    finalBalance = startingBalance + interest;
    years++;

}
System.out.println("Balance after 10 years with annual interest is " + finalBalance);

while (months<120) {
    double interest = startingBalance * interstRateMonthly /12;
    finalBalance = startingBalance + interest;
    months++;
}
System.out.println("Balance after 10 years with monthly interest rate is " +     finalBalance);
```

}

}

Comment: But, then program evaluates just simple interest not "interest on interest"